# Inflating financial numbers

Tags: phrase-requests

What is another way to say “inflating numbers” or “Jack up the numbers” when referring to a company that is using aggressive business practices.

Comment: I don't think "aggressive business practices" has an implication of dishonest or illegal behaviour, but "inflating numbers" and "jacking up the numbers" do. Can you perhaps provide a bit more context for what you're looking for?

Comment: Cooking the books.

Comment: The phrase I am looking for actually indicates aggressive accounting practices to inflate the numbers. Primping the numbers so to say. To make them look better than they are. Cooking the books is one way to express this. But the phrase I am seeking, actually uses the term “numbers” not “books”.

Comment: Creative accounting.

Answer (score -3):

The phrase I was looking for was “Good the numbers”

Comment: Why were you looking for a phrase that is, to say the least, rare to the extent that few would understand it?

Comment: For an article that has a more humorous slant on this subject matter l, so I was looking for the phrase to reflect a more casual ring to it.

Comment: If I had seen "good the numbers" used outside the context of this question I would not have understood what it meant.

Comment: Not a very good phrase, at least in the US.